modifying UDP perl code to modern boost, errors in packet
I have found some old code in perl that will create a packet to be sent off to a program:
the original code.
The relevant part is:
my $discovery_socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(
  Proto => 'udp',
  LocalAddr => '0.0.0.0',
  LocalPort => 3040,
) or die "Can't bind udp/3040: $!";

my $discovery_io = IO::Async::Socket->new(
  handle => $discovery_socket,
  on_recv => sub {
    my ($self, $dgram, $addr) = @_;
    my ($err, $hostname, $portname) = Socket::getnameinfo($addr);
    my (undef, undef, $seq) = unpack "ccna6xx", $dgram;
    print "Received identify with seq $seq from $hostname/$portname\n";
    my $header = pack "ccna6xx",
      0x5a, # magic
      1, # identify reply
      $seq,
      "\x00\x24\x1d\x8b\x0e\x50";
    my $identify = pack "nccccccC4C4C4a4a4a4a32",
      1, 1, 1, 1, # uptime
      1, # mode
      0, # alert
      4, # ip type
      192, 168, 1, 3, # ip addr
      255, 255, 255, 0, # netmask
      192, 168, 1, 1, # gateway
      "\x01\x02\x03\x04", # app ver
      "\x01\x02\x03\x04", # boot ver
      "\x01\x02\x03\x04", # app ver
      "PL ETH/USB"; # name

    send $discovery_socket, $header . $identify, 0, $addr;
  },
  on_recv_error => sub {
    my ($self, $errno) = @_;
    die "recv error $errno on discovery";
  }
);

I've attempted to recreate this with the following function in c++, (plus other surrounding code that probably isn't relevant:
void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                    std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    if (!error || error == boost::asio::error::message_size) {
        std::string hostname = remote_endpoint_.address().to_string();
        unsigned short port = remote_endpoint_.port();
        std::cout << "Received identify from " << hostname << "/" << port << std::endl;
        
        uint16_t seq;
        std::memcpy(&seq, recv_buffer_.data() + 2, sizeof(seq));
        
        // Construct header
        std::array<char, 64> header;
        header[0] = 0x5A; // magic
        header[1] = 1;    // identify reply
        std::memcpy(header.data() + 2, &seq, sizeof(seq));
        std::memcpy(header.data() + 4, "\x00\x24\x1d\x8b\x0e\x50", 6); // eth_addr
        
        // Construct identify reply
        std::array<char, 64> identify_reply;
        std::memset(identify_reply.data(), 0, 4); // uptime
        identify_reply[4] = 1; // mode
        identify_reply[5] = 0; // alert
        identify_reply[6] = 4; // ip type
        std::memcpy(identify_reply.data() + 7, "\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a", 4); // ip addr: 10.10.10.10
        std::memcpy(identify_reply.data() + 11, "\xff\xff\xff\x00", 4); // netmask
        std::memcpy(identify_reply.data() + 15, "\x0a\x0a\x0a\x01", 4); // gateway
        std::memcpy(identify_reply.data() + 19, "\x01\x02\x03\x04", 4); // app ver
        std::memcpy(identify_reply.data() + 23, "\x01\x02\x03\x04", 4); // boot ver
        std::memcpy(identify_reply.data() + 27, "\x01\x02\x03\x04", 4); // hw ver
        std::memcpy(identify_reply.data() + 31, "PL ETH/USB", 10); // name
        
        // Convert header and identify reply to vector of chars
        std::vector<char> send_buffer(header.begin(), header.end());
        send_buffer.insert(send_buffer.end(), identify_reply.begin(), identify_reply.end());
        // Convert packet to vector of strings
        std::vector<std::string> packetStrings = convertPacketToStrings(header, identify_reply,false);
        
        // Print each string to console
        for (const auto& str : packetStrings) {
            std::cout << str << std::endl;
        }
        // Send packet
        socket_.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(send_buffer), remote_endpoint_);
        
        // Start receiving again
        start_receive();
    }
}

The program that send a udp packet to this server code will get a discovery packet as a response, which the program does infact see as follows:

But the IP is not correct, it seems to be some randomly generated sequence of numbers that show up at byte position 21, in the following hex -> decimal sequence, which I highlighted in bold.
90 1 81 79 0 36 29 139 14 80 61 4 1 0 0 0 92 251 245 181 1 128 62 228 104 46 166 107 1 0 0 0 72 46 166 107 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 200 95 59 4 1 0 0 0 16 192 76 1 0 96 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 4 10 10 10 10 255 255 255 0 10 10 10 1 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 80 76 32 69 84 72 47 85 83 66 67 224 74 1 0 0 0 72 69 224 74 1 0 0 0 208 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I'm sure the structure or byte order is wrong somehow, but I don't see it.
Any ideas?

Do you have a problem understanding the Perl code (a Perl question that has nothing to do with C++), or problem implementing some logic in C++ (a question that has noting to do with Perl)? [I assumed the latter and removed the Perl tag. You might want to specify what the Perl code does.]

The C++ code looks strange -- are you sure you want to have a 64-byte header with just the first few bytes initialized?

It was a question trying to understand a program originally written in perl, what functionality I wanted to translate to c++ that had bugs in it, as sehe correctly interpreted.

@ChristianStieber infact no. I admit this is my first foray into anything related to networking at all, I hacked some of this together from other examples without knowing so much how the header was really sized.

Correctly Interpreting The Perl
Looking at the perl docs, n indicates packing a 16bit unsigned big-endian integer:

n  An unsigned short (16-bit) in "network" (big-endian) order.

That implies that pack "nccccccC4C4C4a4a4a4a32" puts the parts at these offsets:
my $identify = pack "nccccccC4C4C4a4a4a4a32",
1, 1, 1, 1,         # uptime n c c c, offset 0
1,                  # mode c,         offset 5
0,                  # alert c,        offset 6
4,                  # ip type c,      offset 7
192, 168, 1, 3,     # ip addr,        offset 8
255, 255, 255, 0,   # netmask,        offset 12
192, 168, 1, 1,     # gateway,        offset 16
"\x01\x02\x03\x04", # app ver,        offset 20
"\x01\x02\x03\x04", # boot ver,       offset 24
"\x01\x02\x03\x04", # app ver,        offset 28
"PL ETH/USB";       # name,           offset 32

I have confirmed this with the simplified perl script:
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# my (undef, undef, $seq) = unpack "ccna6xx", $dgram;
my $seq = 1;

print "Received identify with seq $seq\n";

my $header = pack "ccna6xx",
  0x5a, # magic
  1, # identify reply
  $seq,
  "\x00\x24\x1d\x8b\x0e\x50"; # mac addr of the device (00:24:1d:8b:0e:50)

my $identify = pack "nccccccC4C4C4a4a4a4a32",
  1, 1, 1, 1, # uptime
  1, # mode
  0, # alert
  4, # ip type
  192, 168, 1, 3, # ip addr
  255, 255, 255, 0, # netmask
  192, 168, 1, 1, # gateway
  "\x01\x02\x03\x04", # app ver
  "\x01\x02\x03\x04", # boot ver
  "\x01\x02\x03\x04", # app ver
  "PL ETH/USB"; # name

# print both header and identify as hex arrays to stdout
print join " ", map { sprintf "%02x", $_ } unpack "C*", $header;
print "\n";
print join " ", map { sprintf "%02x", $_ } unpack "C*", $identify;
print "\n";

Which outputs Live On Coliru:
# header
5a 01 00 01 00 24 1d 8b 0e 50 00 00

# identify reply
00 01 01 01 01 01 00 04 c0 a8 01 03 ff ff ff 00 c0 a8 01 01 01 02 03 04 01 02 03 04 01 02 03 04 50 4c 20 45 54 48 2f 55 53 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

So that confirms my counts (see netmask start at offset #12).
Bugs In The C++
Regardless, this doesn't do the same thing:
std::vector<char> send_buffer(header.begin(), header.end());

That adds all header bytes, which is 64 bytes. The perl version only has 12 header bytes. I would probably mimic it like so:
// Construct header
std::vector<uint8_t> header{
    0x5A,                                   // magic
    1,                                      // identify reply
    seq[0], seq[1],                         // seq, still big endian
    0x00,   0x24,   0x1d, 0x8b, 0x0e, 0x50, // eth_addr 00:24:1d:8b:0e:50
    0x00,   0x00                            // trailing xx
};
assert(header.size() == 12);

Now the identify reply could be something like:
// Construct identify reply
std::array<uint8_t, 64> identify_reply{
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, // uptime, mode, alert, ip type
    192, 168, 1, 3,          // ip addr
    255, 255, 255, 0,        // netmask
    192, 168, 1, 1,          // gateway
    1, 2, 3, 4,              // app ver
    1, 2, 3, 4,              // boot ver
    1, 2, 3, 4,              // hw ver
    'P', 'L', ' ', 'E', 'T', 'H', '/', 'U', 'S', 'B' // name
    // 22 (64-42) trailing NUL bytes for free 
};

To deal with the network ordering, you could do e.g.:
uint16_t uptime = ::htons(1);
std::memcpy(identify_reply.data() + 0, &uptime, 2);

Or, vice versa:
uint8_t rawseq[2]; // big endian
std::memcpy(&rawseq, recv_buffer_.data() + 2, sizeof(rawseq));

{
    uint16_t seq;
    std::memcpy(&seq, recv_buffer_.data() + 2, sizeof(seq));
    seq = ntohs(seq);
}

Live C++ Demo
Live On Coliru
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <vector>

void simplified_handle_receive() {
    std::vector<uint8_t> recv_buffer_{0x5A, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x24,
                                      0x1d, 0x8b, 0x0e, 0x50, 0x00, 0x00}; // no idea here, really

    uint8_t rawseq[2];
    std::memcpy(&rawseq, recv_buffer_.data() + 2, sizeof(rawseq));

    {
        uint16_t seq;
        std::memcpy(&seq, recv_buffer_.data() + 2, sizeof(seq));
        seq = ntohs(seq);
    }

    // Construct header
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer{
        0x5A,                                         // magic
        1,                                            // identify reply
        rawseq[0], rawseq[1],                         // seq, still big endian
        0x00,      0x24,      0x1d, 0x8b, 0x0e, 0x50, // eth_addr 00:24:1d:8b:0e:50
        0x00,      0x00                               // trailing xx
    };
    assert(buffer.size() == 12);

    // Construct identify reply
    std::array<uint8_t, 64> identify_reply{
        0,   1,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   4, // uptime, mode, alert, ip type
        192, 168, 1,   3,                     // ip addr
        255, 255, 255, 0,                     // netmask
        192, 168, 1,   1,                     // gateway
        1,   2,   3,   4,                     // app ver
        1,   2,   3,   4,                     // boot ver
        1,   2,   3,   4,                     // hw ver
        'P', 'L', ' ', 'E', 'T', 'H', '/', 'U',
        'S', 'B' // name
        // 22 (64-42) trailing NUL bytes for free
    };


    fmt::print("Header:         {::02x}\n", buffer);
    fmt::print("Identify reply: {::02x}\n", identify_reply);

    buffer.insert(buffer.end(), identify_reply.begin(), identify_reply.end());
    fmt::print("Header + Identify reply: {::02x}\n", buffer);
};

int main() {
    simplified_handle_receive();
}

Printing
Header:         [5a, 01, 00, 01, 00, 24, 1d, 8b, 0e, 50, 00, 00]
Identify reply: [00, 01, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 04, c0, a8, 01, 03, ff, ff, ff, 00, c0, a8, 01, 01, 01, 02, 03, 04, 01, 02, 03, 04, 01, 02, 03, 04, 50, 4c, 20, 45, 54, 48, 2f, 55, 53, 42, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00]
Header + Identify reply: [5a, 01, 00, 01, 00, 24, 1d, 8b, 0e, 50, 00, 00, 00, 01, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 04, c0, a8, 01, 03, ff, ff, ff, 00, c0, a8, 01, 01, 01, 02, 03, 04, 01, 02, 03, 04, 01, 02, 03, 04, 50, 4c, 20, 45, 54, 48, 2f, 55, 53, 42, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00]


Added C++ version demo for comparison Live On Coliru

Thank you so much! everythings working great now :)
